# Calling a function before Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button that calls function A()

When I click on it I want the calls to be made in that order:

```
A()
Page_Load()
```

Right now it's doing:

```
Page_Load()
A()
```

Is there a way around that or is it just by design and there's nothing I can do about it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use a HTML Submit button and check to see if it is in the Form on every postback in Page_Init

```
public void Page_Init(object o, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["MyButtonName"]))
     {
          A();
     }
}
```

And in your ASP.NET code:

```
<Button Type="Submit" Name="MyButtonName" Value="Press Here To Do Stuff Early!" />
```

I think that will work.

Comment: I'm the king of the nasty hack.

Comment: It's nasty but I love it! +1 too and if it works and nothing cleaner comes up I'll accept that

Comment: You might give Rune FS a little upvote love... he was in technically a few seconds before me with the same answer.

Comment: True that RuneFS' answer is also nice. I accept this one because it made more sense to me and helped me fix my issue. I still upvoted runefs'

Comment: @marcgg thx for the upvote and it would seem I need to work on my coomunication skills my solution is perfect match of Anderson (with no code to explain it) crets to you Anderson for supplying the example and being a good sport :)

Answer (score 7):

Control events (such as the click events of buttons) are called after page_load. The controls are not guarenteed to be fully initialized prior to page_load. If you really need to call a function before page_load has been called based on whether a button has been pressed you'll have to examine the request to check if the button has been pressed (basically old school ASP)

Answer (score 5):

You need to call your function in the Page_Init.  Page_Init will happen before Page_Load.

Here's an [Overview of the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: But I want my function to be called when you press a button, not on every page load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I checked your link this is not really want I'm looking for. I'm trying to do something when a button is pressed. I'm not sure how to go doing that with the information you put here.

Comment: He does not want to call any method he wants an event handler called before page_load

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly: ASP.NET will always call `Page_Load` before handling postback events like `Button_Click`.

However, you can accomplish what you want by redirecting to your page after handling the postback event. (Using [the Post-Redirect-Get pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).)

Inside your Page_Load method, you can avoid running any relevant code twice by checking to see if it's a postback first:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack) {
    // Do something resource-intensive that you only want to do on GETs
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Jeff Sternal answered, The Post-Redirect-Get pattern is a good way of solving a problem like this.

In my circumstances i had a calendar and if you clicked a date it would add that to a scheduler. The scheduler would have buttons on each new date that needed to have onclick functions tied to them.

Because the new row was being added with a linkbutton(on the calendar), in the code the new scheduler date was being added at the Postback event handling meaning that the new set of buttons wouldn't have a command tied to them.

[The page life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[Post Get Redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, at least, not in the way described by your question. When you click a button it will send a request to the server which in turn will start processing it, and follow the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle as posted by Joseph.

Alternatively you could try making an AJAX call to a page without reloading the current one you're on and do whatever processing you require.

Comment: I could direct your attention to several impossible feats if you wish, but there are always alternatives... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do for Page Init is called before Page Load. 
 
Take a look at the ASP.net Page Life Cycle

```
public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //CALL YOU FUNCTION A()    
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your actual goal here is to have your "page loading code" happen after your event handler runs -- for example, if clicking your button changes something in your database, and you want the updated data to be reflected on the page when it loads -- then you could have your "page loading code" get called from a method that gets called *later* in the [ASP.NET page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) than your event handler, such as `Page_PreRender`, instead of calling it from `Page_Load`.

For example, here's a simplified excerpt from an .aspx.cs page class that has a button event handler that runs before the page population logic, and a confirmation message that is visible on the page only after the button was clicked:

```
// Runs *before* the button event handler
protected void Page_Load() {
    _myConfirmationMessage.Visible = false;
}

// Runs *after* the button event handler
protected void Page_PreRender() {
    // (...Code to populate page controls with database data goes here...)
}

// Event handler for an asp:Button on the page
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // (...Code to update database data goes here...)
    _myConfirmationMessage.Visible = true;
}
```