# How to trigger SelectedIndexChange before postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My page has two controls and the content of the second depending on the dropdown in the first one. I have an issue because the event SelectedIndexChange is triggered after my postback.

I tried with an update panel and a trigger but it doesn't work.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="form-control"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlTest" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any idea to force the event "SelectedIndexChange" before the postback ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364346/calling-a-function-before-page-load

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  Please tell me what you want to achieve with the dropdown list change event handler and can help you do it before the postback on the client:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm11.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm11" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ddlTest").change(function () {
                alert($("#ddlTest option:selected").text());
                alert($("#ddlTest option:selected").val());
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTest" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="aText" Value="aValue" />
             <asp:ListItem Text="bText" Value="bValue" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```